# How to log to different files according to source file in python?

Tags: python, logging

I configure my logger like this:

```
with open('logging.yaml', 'rt') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
```

the `logging.yaml` is:

```
formatters:

    colored:
        (): colorlog.ColoredFormatter
        format: "%(log_color)s%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)-10s%(reset)s | %(message)s"

    simple:
        format: "[%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)10s() ] %(message)s"
        info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: simple
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8
```

So the problem is that I have many modules using `logging.yaml`, it means they all redirect to `info.log`, can I **redirect them into different files**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mention about logger config in logging

```
'loggers': {
         'test_a': {                  
             'handlers': ['default_1'],        
             'level': 'INFO',  
             'propagate': True  
         }, 
         'test_b': {                  
             'handlers': ['default_2'],        
             'level': 'INFO',  
             'propagate': True  
         }
     }
```

In my example, if log write in test_a module will be handle by default_1, and log write in test_b module will be handble by default_2.

More detail
http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/good-logging-practice-in-python/